# Hidden whitespace char causing preg_match to return false

Tags: php, regex

I have a strange problem and I apologise if the title does not make much sense as I cant seem to word it right.

Basically I am trying to check if a certain string is only numbers, for this I am using regluar expressions

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $ordernumber[1]);
```

this is where it gets hard to explain from debugging I have learned that `$ordernumber[1]` which should be `"41720"` when `var dumped $ordernumber[1]` has a string length of *6* when there is only *5 numerical digits* in there.

Which leads me to believe there is a whitespace character in that string which is not accounted for in the regex.

**How do I find out which whitespace/special character is in the string?**

**attached is a picture of the dump along with the result of the preg match which is 0/false.**

Note the string length

Thank you for reading.

Just figured out If I use `preg_match("/^[0-9]+$\D/", $ordernumber[1]);` \D(non-digit)then it does return true, which solves my issue, would still like to know what character it is though, if anyone knows how to find out.

Answer below which will trim whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string, would actually do what I wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried modifying your regex to

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", trim($ordernumber[1]));
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I figured out where to edit the regex but this would do exactly what I asked for, so I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks for the info on the useful function!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what character is in the string, just do:

```
echo bin2hex($string);
```